# Is there a standard C++ Hash Container?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, standard-library

I have a variety of textbooks that note that there wasn't a hash container originally incorporated into the STL, but most also say that most standard library implementations do have some form of hash container since it was a known shortfall.

These books aren't necessarily as up to date as possible, and I got a little confused about what was really "standard" when googling, so:

At this point in time, do most standard library implementations provide a fairly consistent hash container, and if so, is it considered a part of the STL?

What's the "standard" header for this container? (I'm guessing it's `#include <hash>`, but just in case!).

Is there a hash set and hash map separately defined for use?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653097/stl-hash-functions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The new standard hash map container is called `unordered_map`. You can include it in your files by `#include <unordered_map>`. It is part of the now-approved standard C++11.

Before C++11, you had various things like `hash_map` which were (widely?) supported by some vendors so you could use them, but if you did, your code wasn't really portable because `hash_map` wasn't part of the standard. `hash_map` and all the other vendor-specific versions of a hash table structure shouldn't be used now.

Comment: don't forget the quasi standards `boost::unordered_map` and co, which were the experimentation ground for the current standard and thus provide an easy transition.

Answer (score 6):

See C++11 types:

- `unordered_map`
- `unordered_set`
- `unordered_multimap`
- `unordered_multiset`

Comment: And their boost counterparts for non C++11 compiler users.

Answer (score 2):

Not in the current standard (03), you can use `boost::unordered_map`. In the new standard there will be, `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 1):

The new C++11 standard has hash-equivalent containers. They are not in most implementations at this time, but they have been in TR1 extensions to the standard library, which are provided with some implementations.

Answer (score 1):

There are some hash containers in the TR1 namespace. See for example a short intro here: http://drdobbs.com/184402066

Comment: The tr1 namespace is already old. With the C++0x version of the standard practically here everything has rolled from tr1 into std.

Comment: I thought C++0x is still in the draft, isn't it?

Comment: Yes the standard is still in draft but all the good compilers have already moved stuff out of tr1 into std (with the appropriate flag).